# formula to populate sequential number in columns based on cell value in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

How can I sequentially populate columns based on a number from another cell? I have a Document# and Number of steps (either a count, or "all") in 1 tab, and in another tab - I need the formula to populate the Count (going up in increments of 10) horizontally. I want the count to change if the Document# changes. Help would be greatly appreciated!

[image]

I can get the total step count using vlookup, but not sure how to enter the right number of columns.

Comment: So what are you using for the total step count? Please share that, it helps us help you, since with given info it's guessing what you mean. PS `SEQUENCE has a step argument, so the lookup value divided by 10, with start clvalie 10, step 10 would be the direction.

Comment: And what does `All` mean?  It is hard to split a text string into steps of 10.

Comment: Total step count is basically subsections within the document - for example - document# 1 has 10 sections (going up in increments of 10), document# 2 has 5 sections, and so on. Its fixed/defined. In Document #3 and 5, its listed as "all" because it only has 1 section.

Comment: @scottcraner - "All" means the document doesn't have sub-sections - it has just 1 single section.

Answer (score 2):

This will return a `10` when `All` and the steps by 10 if number.

If the selected document is not found it returns and empty string `""`

```
=IFERROR(SEQUENCE(,IFERROR(XLOOKUP(E6,A:A,B:B,0)/10,1),10,10),"")
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

---

Per comments"

```
=IFERROR(SEQUENCE(,IFERROR(XLOOKUP(E6,A:A,B:B,0)/10,0),10,10),"All")
```

Comment: You are a Genius. Thank you!!

Follow up question - is there anyway to convert "All" into "all" and not "10"? I dont have any issues with "not found" or incorrect entry - because all my entry fields are tied to dropdowns that're auto-populated, so I dont have to worry about incorrect entries *hopefully*

Also- can you help me understand how your formula populates all the way through to all the rows automatically? What part of the syntax does that?

Answer (score 1):

`=SEQUENCE(,XLOOKUP(E6,A2:A7,IFERROR(B2:B7/10,1)),10,10)`

This returns the sequence of the lookup value divided by 10, which returns an error in case of `All`; then it returns `1` with start value 10 step 10.